# How to "unshare" a video in iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, video, sharing

I shared a home video on my iPhone with myself via iCloud using my cell phone number. I was hoping that this would allow me to see the file somehow on my Mac but alas that did not work. I'm assuming this video is now using space on my iCloud account, so I'd like to "unshare" and delete it. How is this done?

Follow-up question, the video in question was added twice. I'm able to delete the videos as suggested in in the selected answer, however I'm now left with an empty stream that says "shared by (null)(null)". How do I get rid of that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you've added a video to an iCloud Shared Photo Stream. Since you are the one that added it to the stream, you can delete it.

> **Can I delete photos, videos and comments from a shared stream?**
>
> Yes. If you are the owner of a shared stream, you can delete any photos, videos or comments that you or your contributors have added.

<sup>Source: Apple KB article: [iCloud Photo Sharing FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5902)</sup>

To delete a video from a shared stream:

1. Go to **Photos** → **Shared**.

   [image]
2. Select the stream that you added the video to, then select the video.
3. Tap the **Trash** <sub>[image]</sub> icon to delete it.

To delete the entire shared stream:

1. Go to **Photos** → **Shared**.
2. Select the stream that you wish to delete.
3. Go to **People** → **Delete Photo Stream**.

With regard to your statement about using up iCloud storage…

> **Do Shared Photo Streams use my iCloud storage?**
>
> No. Photos uploaded to Shared Photo Streams do not count against your iCloud storage.

<sup>Source: Apple KB article: [iCloud Photo Sharing FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5902)</sup>

Comment: This worked. Appreciate the answers to both questions. However I'm now left with a empty stream listed as "shared by (null)(null)" can I get rid of that somehow?

Comment: @MarkEdington My answer details how to delete an entire shared stream :)

Comment: Hmm. I was able to click on the "unsubscribe" option and that removed it. However, I never saw any option labeled "Delete Photo Stream" I actually deleted each of the duplicate shared videos individually first.

Comment: @MarkEdington "Delete Photo Stream" will show only if you are the owner of the stream. The button will be replaced by "Unsubscribe" if you don't own the stream.